# Excel file generated using Aspose is corrupted when using password

Tags: excel, aspose

I am creating excel file using `Apose.cells API` :

```
book.SetEncryptionOptions(EncryptionType.XOR, 40);
book.SetEncryptionOptions(EncryptionType.StrongCryptographicProvider, 128);
book.Settings.Password = "test;
```

When I try to open the generated excel file, it prompts for password and after keying the correct password, the file opens with the following error message

```
"Excel found unreadable content". Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes

<info>Excel recovered your formulas and cell values, but some data may have been lost.</info>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this issue is specific to your Excel file. Please provide your Excel file for testing.

We tested this issue with the [most recent version i.e. 18.4.6](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0tzj04e2stk4aug/Aspose.Cells18.4.6%20For%20.Net2_AuthenticodeSigned.Zip?dl=0) and it works fine. Please see the following code. It loads the [Book1.xls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzjha1m3bger1ft/NSN-Sample%20Input%20and%20Output%20Excel%20Files.zip?dl=0) which has **Macros** and after executing your code, it saves it as [output.xls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzjha1m3bger1ft/NSN-Sample%20Input%20and%20Output%20Excel%20Files.zip?dl=0) which opens fine in Microsoft Excel without any errors as you have mentioned.

**Download Link:**

- [Sample Input and Output Excel Files.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzjha1m3bger1ft/NSN-Sample%20Input%20and%20Output%20Excel%20Files.zip?dl=0)

**C#**

```
Workbook book = new Workbook("Book1.xls");
book.SetEncryptionOptions(EncryptionType.XOR, 40);
book.SetEncryptionOptions(EncryptionType.StrongCryptographicProvider, 128);
book.Settings.Password = "test123";
book.Save("output.xls");
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose